# Why does the Background of my "game" move?

Tags: java, image

I'm trying to teach myself some java and I'm currently trying to code a "game". 
So far I have a controllable circle...

This is what i have so far:

Window-class

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Window extends GameIntern{

    public void init(){
        setSize(854,480);   
        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
        offscreen = createImage(854,480);
        d = offscreen.getGraphics();
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        d.clearRect(0,0,854,480);
        d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
        d.drawOval(x, y, 30, 30);
        g.drawImage(offscreen,x,y,this);
    }

    public void update(Graphics g){
        paint(g);
    }
}
```

and Game-class

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class GameIntern extends Applet implements Runnable , KeyListener {
    public int x,y;
    public Image offscreen;
    public Graphics d;
    public boolean up,down,left,right;
    public BufferedImage background , face;
    public void run() {
        x = 100;
        y = 100;
        try {
            background = ImageIO.read(new File("background.png"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(true){
            if(left == true){
                x-=3;
                repaint();
            }
            if(right == true){
                x+=3;
                repaint();
            }
            if(up == true){
                y-=3;
                repaint();
            }
            if(down == true){
                y+=3;
                repaint();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if(e.getKeyCode() == 37){
            left=true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 38){
            up=true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 39){
            right=true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 40){
            down=true;
        }

    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        if(e.getKeyCode() == 37){
            left=false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 38){
            up=false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 39){
            right=false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 40){
            down=false;
        }

    }


    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
}
```

Now to my problem. When I start the Thread and move around via arrow-keys, the background moves as well. 
Why is that and how can I fix that issue? 
I never change the x and y coordinates of the Image.

Any help or criticism is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the definition of the `repaint()` method in the code you initially posted - could it be added?

Comment: What is `offscreen`? It's depending on the `x` amd `y` variables, which you modify when a key is pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do your actual drawing you do `g.drawImage(offscreen,x,y,this);`. This draws your offscreen image with it's upper left at `x,y` (which have been adjusted when you moved the circle).

You need to use `g.drawImage(offscreen,0,0,this);` to draw the entire offscreen image at the same place all the time.

Comment: Wow I seemed to overlook that. Thank you very much for the fast answer. It works like intended now :)
I'll accept your answer as soon as possible.